# Feathersjs 4 oAuth with AWS Cognito not working

Tags: amazon-cognito, feathersjs

I've been trying to make FeathersJS 4.5 oAuth module work with AWS Cognito with no luck. I have made a specific authentication strategy as given in the example

https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/authentication/auth0.html#strategy

and changed all parameters to be relevant for Cognito (of course). The content of my authentication file is similar to the code below.

```
const { AuthenticationService, JWTStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication');
const { LocalStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local');
const { expressOauth, OAuthStrategy } = require('@feathersjs/authentication-oauth');

class CognitoStrategy extends OAuthStrategy {

  async getProfile(data, _params) {
    return await super.getProfile(data, _params);
  }  
    
  async getEntityData(profile) {
    return await super.getEntityData(profile);    
  }
}

class GitHubStrategy extends OAuthStrategy {
  async getEntityData(profile) {
    const baseData = await super.getEntityData(profile);

    return {
      ...baseData,
      // You can also set the display name to profile.name
      name: profile.login,
      // The GitHub profile image
      avatar: profile.avatar_url,
      // The user email address (if available)
      email: profile.email
    };
  }
}

module.exports = app => {
  const authentication = new AuthenticationService(app);

  authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy());
  authentication.register('local', new LocalStrategy());
  authentication.register('cognito', new CognitoStrategy());  
  authentication.register('github', new GitHubStrategy());  
  
  app.use('/authentication', authentication);
  app.configure(expressOauth());

}
```

but haven't had much luck putting it all together. The error I get is

> Stack:TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile_url' of undefined
>     at Object.module.exports [as default] (/home/ivan/Projects/InTouch-backend/node_modules/grant-profile/lib/client.js:53:57)
>     at CognitoStrategy. (/home/ivan/Projects/InTouch-backend/node_modules/@feathersjs/authentication-oauth/lib/strategy.js:66:36)
>     at Generator.next ()

My oAuth configuration is:

```
"oauth" : {
    "defaults" : {
        "path" : "/oauth",
        "host" : "localhost:3030",
        "protocol" : "http",
        "transport" : "session"
    },
    "github" : {
        "key" : "xyz",
        "secret" : "xyz",
        "redirect_uri" : "http://localhost:3030/oauth/github/callback",
        "scope" : [ 
          "opened", 
          "email", 
          "profile"
        ]
    },
    "cognito" : {
        "key" : "xyz...",
        "secret" : "xyz...",
        "subdomain" : "xyz.amazoncognito.com",
        "scope" : [ 
          "opened", 
          "profile", 
          "email"
        ]
    }
}
```

A very similar setup for GitHub works like a charm.

I have also found a few good solutions on the internet e.g.

https://blog.feathersjs.com/how-to-setup-oauth-flow-with-featherjs-522bdecb10a8
https://blog.feathersjs.com/enterprise-grade-authentication-using-aws-cognito-and-onelogin-with-feathersjs-d4c6f46ab123

but they are relevant for FeathersJS 3.x and they don't work anymore since the authentication service is redesigned.

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving this in case someone needs it. The configuration below worked for me.

```
{   
 "authStrategies" : [ "local", "jwt", "cognito" ],
 "oauth" : {
   "redirect" : "http://localhost:3030/index.html",
   "defaults" : {
        "path" : "/oauth",
        "host" : "localhost:3030",
        "protocol" : "http",
        "transport" : "session"
    },
    "cognito" : {
         "key" : "#APPKEY#",
         "secret" : "#APPSECRET#",
         "authorize_url" : "https://[subdomain]/oauth2/authorize",
         "access_url" : "https://[subdomain]/oauth2/token",
         "profile_url" : "https://[subdomain]/oauth2/userInfo",
         "oauth" : 2,
         "scope_delimiter" : " ",
         "subdomain" : "#XYZ.amazoncognito.com#",
         "scope" : [ 
             "openid", 
             "profile", 
             "email"
          ],
          "usernameField" : "username"                    
    }
  }
}
```

"[subdomain]" should stay as it is it will be replaced by the oAuth module.